# Create and update in same form

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to use the same view to create and update entries, the create is working fine, but when I try to update, I get this SQL syntax error but I can't see the syntax error in the model

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE articles SET title = 'ewe', text = 'ew', category_id = '1' WHERE id = '1'' at line 1

```
<?php

    use App\Model\ArticleModel;

    if(isset($article)) { 
      $id = $article['id'];
      $title = $article['title'];
      $text = $article['text'];
      $category_id = $article['category_id'];

      $action = "?page=form&id=$id";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      $title = $_POST['title'];
      $text = $_POST['text'];
      $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];

      if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $this->modelName->update($id,$title, $text, $category_id);
        // $this->modelName is actually correct, it is defined in the core
      } else {
        $this->modelName->create($title, $text, $category_id);
      }
      header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>

<div class="container">
<h1>Save Article</h1>
<form action="<?= isset($action)?$action:'?page=form' ?>" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input name="title" value="<?= !empty($title)?$title:'' ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="title" aria-describedby="title">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <textarea name="text" class="form-control" id="text"><?= !empty($text)?$text:'' ?></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select name="category_id" value="<?= !empty($category_id)?$category_id:'' ?>" id="category" class="form-control">
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
            <option value="<?= $category["id"] ?>" <?php if(isset($article) && $category["id"] == $article['category_id']) { echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>><?= $category["name"] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
</div>
```

**ArticleModel**

```
public function create($title, $text, $category_id) {
        return $this->db->save(
            'INSERT INTO articles SET title = ?, text = ?, category_id = ?', [$title, $text, $category_id]
        );
    }

public function update($id, $title, $text, $category_id) {
        return $this->db->save(
            "UPDATE TABLE articles SET title = ?, text = ?, category_id = ? WHERE id = ?", [$title, $text, $category_id, $id]
        );
    }
```

I suspect the error being from $action and the $_GET['id'], but I can't find how to fix this

Comment: Please do not edit out the original error for which you have been provided a solution. If you have another error accept the answer her and post another question.

Answer (score 2):

In your update function. This is invalid SQL syntax `UPDATE TABLE articles ...`. It should read `UPDATE articles ...`

Comment: SQL syntax error disappeared, but values aren't updated, any idea ?

Comment: Have you checked your server's error logs @mohsen?

Comment: @JayBlanchard what do you mean ? (beginner in PHP)

Comment: Every server has error logs. When something doesn't work those errors are logged.

Comment: Also, check/debug the return values for your update/create calls. It is a bad practice to just assume the calls will work (as the first code block currently does).

Comment: @AD7six when I var_dump the update() return value, it only returns 'null'

Comment: @mohsen The code for `$this->db->save` isn't in the question. but if it returns null - that's either an error, or another bad practice :). Since you're (now) asking about the behavior of code that isn't in the question, I'm VTC.